# How to add entities to Db Context and re-set the grid's data source

Tags: c#, database, linq, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am using Entity framework and pulling my data to a grid. I have a popup form that will let me add a new item, and if I click OK it will add it to the database context. Like this:

```
private void tsb_AddGroup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var group = new PeriodicReportGroup();

        frmGroups frm = new frmGroups(group);
        if (DialogResult.OK == frm.ShowDialog())
        {
            Database.PeriodicReportGroups.Add(group);
        }
        InitGrid();
    }
```

Then, after the dialog is closed, I want my grid to refresh and have the new item that I just added. However, since the item I added to the context has been *instantiated by me*, instead of read of the database, when I debug my code I can see that although my database context does contain it, it has a different type than all the other items: the one I added is of type

```
{ReportData.PeriodicReportGroup}
```

while the other ones are of type

```
{System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.PeriodicReportGroup_3FCAD12B682C11C86AC1CF299E0617B21F74CC5F468C3577CE33B51A8CF38372}
```

So when I set my Db context entity to the grid's data source, the new one gets lost in the way and it will not show in the grid.

I have found a way to work around this, which is using the `Local` property:

```
gridGroups.DataSource = Database.PeriodicReportGroups.Local.ToList().Cast<IPeriodicReportGroup>().OrderBy(g => g.Name).ToList( );
```

This will work as long as the Db context entity has been referenced before. Which makes it a necessity to have some garbage code to make it work the first time we load the grid, like this:

```
if (Database.PeriodicReportGroups.Local.Count == 0)
        {
            var data = Database.PeriodicReportGroups.ToList();
        }
```

I can't believe there isn't a better way to do this. Anybody can offer some ideas? Thanks!